# easy Qt widget to draw lines and shapes (like the tkinter canvas)?

Tags: python, pyside2

I used to create GUIs with tkinter but i am trying to switch to PySide2 (which is way more customisable) but a can't find any PySide2 widget to replace the tkinter.canvas that i was using with tkinter.

I tried to use the QtGui.Qpainter widget but it seems very complicated compared to the tkinter canvas and I can't figure out how it works.

Did someone know an easy to use pyside widget which let me draw lines and shapes on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar to [Tkinter Canvas Widget](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm) is [Qt Graphics Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) that uses QGraphicsItems similar to Canvas Items. Since you don't ask for a specific example I will implement an example from the Tkinter docs to Qt:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *


master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

w.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)
w.create_line(0, 100, 200, 0, fill="red", dash=(4, 4))

w.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="blue")

mainloop()
```

[image]

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 100))
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(
        scene, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter
    )
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    view.setBackgroundBrush(
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
        .standardPalette()
        .brush(QtGui.QPalette.Background)
    )
    view.setWindowTitle("Qt")

    line1 = scene.addLine(0, 0, 200, 100)
    line2 = scene.addLine(0, 100, 200, 0)
    pen = QtGui.QPen()
    pen.setDashPattern((4, 4))
    pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor("red"))
    line2.setPen(pen)

    rect = scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(50, 25), QtCore.QPointF(150, 75)))
    rect.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("blue"))

    view.resize(200, 100)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

#### Equivalent items

```
| Tk Items  | Qt Items                                                      |
|-----------|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| arc       | QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsPathItem                       |
| bitmap    | QGraphicsPixmapItem                                           |
| image     | QGraphicsPixmapItem                                           |
| line      | QGraphicsLineItem, QGraphicsPathItem                          |
| oval      | QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsPathItem                       |
| polygon   | QGraphicsPolygonItem, QGraphicsPathItem                       |
| rectangle | QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsPathItem                          |
| text      | QGraphicsSimpleTextItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsPathItem |
| window    | QGraphicsProxyWidget                                          |
```